# HTML inside Localization strings (in Laravel)

Tags: laravel, localization, lumen

How can use HTML inside localization strings?

**lang/en/messages.php**

```
  "save" => "<i class='fa fa-save'></i> Save text",
```

**page.blade.php**
These codes print the string with html as plain string:

```
<input value="{{ trans('messages.save') }}" />
or
<input value="{!! trans('messages.save') !!}" />
```

Comment: The `value` attribute does not accept HTLM within it so what you are trying to achieve will make no sense

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" replacing the `input` with a `button`:

```
  <button type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> {{ trans('messages.save') }}
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to localization in the blade file laravel

```
<input value="@lang('messages.save')" />
```